# i dont understand what doing froala WYSIWYG html editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, wysiwyg, froala

why when i load froala`s cdn js i see this warnings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awbzW.png)

I didn't find any information about why this happens, and does it mean that this html editor is trying to hack me?

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about this, this html editor is not trying to hack your

From [the mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#invalid_domains) :

> A cookie for a domain that does not include the server that set it should be rejected by the user agent

It's probably because you use the cdn of froala`s (on their domain name)